# How Can I Convert Tabs To Spaces Using Rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

A colleague accidentally committed a large number of changes with tabs instead of spaces. I want to rebase and amend that commit and change all the tabs to spaces.

I **don't** want to change **all** the tabs in the file though.

I want to change the tabs in **just** the diffs.

Is there a git command to do this or will it have to be a script?

There are too many files and changes to do it manually and I don't want to use git filter branch